# Get-ADUser entire forest

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Sorry if this is something that has been answered before but I've been searching for days and cannot find anything like what I'm looking for (which is baffling because it seems like the simplest request).

I have a script that traces a delegate tree (irrelevant) and within it, I need to be able to reliably execute Get-ADUser for a specific user against the entire directory and I have not found a way to do this yet that doesn't involve 100 lines of code. We have four domains in our forest:
na.ds.company.com
la.ds.company.com
ea.ds.company.com
ap.ds.company.com

Why is this so simple to do in ADUC and so hard to do in Powershell?

Comment: This is not 100 lines of code http://techjambu.blogspot.ca/2012/04/forest-wide-search-using-ad-cmdles.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Active Directory Powershell - forest-wide search script using .csv list of users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754987/active-directory-powershell-forest-wide-search-script-using-csv-list-of-users) You should be able to use the logic there. Look for the _Final Script_ its less than 12 lines

Comment: Thanks guys, the reason I'm trying to avoid making a function out of this is because i need to make sure I end up with only one result and that it's the correct result and I need to then manipulate that data inline with other commands so it becomes a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by referencing a GC domain controller in the root directory and the GC port on that DC (3268). I tried this before but I think the problem was that the GC I tried was not located in the root. The command ended up being:

```
Get-ADUser <userID> -Server <GC located in root>:3268
```