# Power Shell Output list of all Active Directory users and all groups each user is a member of (csv)

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Code:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices")
$rootEnt = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
$res = $searcher.FindAll()
foreach ($r in $res) {$r.Properties['memberOf', 'sAMAccountName'] }
```

This Code is giving me results like:

```
PLXXXXX 
ADGroup1
ADGroup2
ADGroup3
CZYYYYY
Group1
ADGroup2
ADGroup3
ADGroup4
CHAAAAA
ADGroup10
ADGroup20
```

Can somebody modify this code to have results like this file?:

```
sAMAccountName               ADGroups
--------------               --------
PLXXXXX                      ADGroup1, ADGroup2, ADGroup3
CZYYYYY                      ADGroup1, ADGroup2, ADGroup3, ADGroup4
CHAAAAA                      ADGroup10, ADGroup20
```

I would like to store it into CSV file also.

Regards!

Comment: I don't think there is a folder named `Temp` on your `E:` drive. `Could not find a part of the path 'E:\temp\1.csv'.`

Comment: Sorry i pasted wrong error. I edited post and now the error is correct

Comment: What's the new error?  I just ran both of your code snippets on my Windows 2012 R2 test system, only changing the export path, and both worked.

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "shell" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."

Comment: Entire Post has been modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices") | Out-Null
$rootEnt = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
$res = $searcher.FindAll()

Write-Host Found ($res.count) users

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($r in $res) {
    $properties = $r | select -ExpandProperty Properties

    $sAMAccountName = $properties.samaccountname[0]
    $ADGroups = if ($properties.memberof) { $properties.memberof -join “;” | Out-String } else { '' }

    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $sAMAccountName; "ADGroups" = $ADGroups; }
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users

$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding UTF8 -Path here
```

Some explanations:

- $r is a System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult which has a Path and Properties. So first thing we do is to get the properties into a variable $properties,
- $properties is a ResultPropertyValueCollection, in our case the values we're interested in are always the first hence the [0],
- then a custom object is created with the values we're interested in. We add those to an array list,
- Finally we export to csv. In this example I set the delimiter to TAB and export to a file called 'here' but of course you're free to choose.

Hope it helps!

***edit***
Here is another version which is using the ActiveDirectory module. You may need to install it if the script gives you an error. To install

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

And here is the script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf

Write-Host Found ($users.count) users

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sAMAccountName = $user.name

# might be slower but easier to read
$groups = ($user.MemberOf | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ',';

# if too slow do this instead, equivalent to the first script
# $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }

    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.name; "ADGroups" = $groups}
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users

$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding UTF8 -Path here
```

Using -Filter * should give you a complete list.

***edit*** Final version based on your script (just a refinement on config)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$configs = @(
    @{name="europe"; server="europe.mycompanyname.com"; file="E:\temp\europe.csv"},
    @{name="nmea"; server="nmea.mycompanyname.com"; file="E:\temp\nmea.csv"},
    @{name="asiapacific"; server="asiapacific.mycompanyname.com"; file="E:\temp\asiapacific.csv"},
    @{name="americas"; server="americas.mycompanyname.com"; file="E:\temp\americas.csv"}
    )

foreach($config in $configs) {
    $users = Get-ADUser -Server $config.server -Filter * -Properties MemberOf

    Write-Host Found ($users.count) users from $config.name

    $list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        $sAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname
        $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }
        $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.samaccountname; "ADGroups" = $groups;}
        $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users from $config.name

    $list | Export-Csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -Path $config.file
}
```

Comment: $ADGroups will only have one group because memberof is a collection and you only selecting the first element.

Comment: Thank you BenH! I fixed the script accordingly.

Comment: I added into the code $searcher.PageSize = 950 but i still missing about 70k of users. Your code gives me only 60k of results which is about 50% of the total. Anyone knows what could be the reason? searcher filter is not a reason becouse i have simillar C# code for something else and it gives me about 130k of results with the same searcher filter.

Comment: I can't say for sure, I do not have such a large AD to test it on. I added a couple of Write-Hosts : this will give you the number of users found, and the number of users processed. This could give us an indication on what is going wrong.

Comment: Found 63106 users
Processed 63106 users so in my opinion it should be related with searcher filter. But this is strange, because  similar code in C#  with the same searcher filter gives me 140k users in result. Do you have any idea how to modify searcher filter to obtain more users? can i just delete searcher filter for this code? is there any option to have "*" in searcher filter?

Comment: I added another version of the script which is using AD cmdlets. Using a * filter should give you a complete list. Also, the Get-ADGroup cmdlet gives you simple group names instead of full DN names (but it might be slower, especially with 70k users!)

Comment: with $groups = ($user.MemberOf | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ','; the result is Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=xxx,OU=xxx_3,OU=xxxx,OU=xx,DC=xxx,DC=com' under: 'DC=asiapacific,DC=abb,DC=com'. At my path:14 char:34 + $groups = ($user.MemberOf | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ',';
+CategoryInfo:ObjectNotFound:CN=800xA_CIT_CC...s,DC=xxx,DC=com:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId:ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

Comment: with $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' } the result is 
Found 33250 users
Processed 33250 users and funny part is these users are users from DC:ASIAPACIFIC, DC:mycompany, DC.com. We have also AMERICAS, NMEA and EUROPE. And the results are not including these.

Comment: The best results was achieved by the first version of the code but still missing 70k of users. Performance was also the best in the first version.

Comment: I do not know the topology of your DC, but it may well be you're looking at an entire forest :) therefore you may need to specify which AD server you want to target: `Get-ADUser <userID> -Server <GC located in root>:3268`. See [Get-ADUser entire forest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681880/get-aduser-entire-forest) for more details / explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The AD cmdlets from RSAT are usually better if you are looking to get nicely formatted PowerShell objects. But here's an example of how you could accomplish what you are looking for using your existing code. Just replace your foreach loop with this:

```
$output = foreach ($r in $res) {
    [string]$memberof = $r.properties.memberof
    [string]$sam = $r.properties.samaccountname
    [pscustomobject]@{sAMAccountName=$sam;ADGroups=$memberof}
}
$output
$output | Export-CSV C:\example\output.csv -notype
```

Edited to explictly cast output to string to fix csv output.

Comment: would you consider to write this code in AD cmdlets from RSAT instead what i have here? As you said it is usually better. Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW your code is giving me csv results like :                 sAMAccountName ADGroups
System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection
System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection
System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection
System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection

Comment: Edited my response to cast `$memberof` and `$sam` to string so that it exports correctly to csv

Comment: Found 63116 users
Processed 63116 users it also missing 70k of users but strange thing is there are some accounts in your querry that are missing in the Cebe querry and also there are some accounts in Cebe querry that are missing in your querry. I have no idea what is the reason. i will try to play with the searcher filter maybe this is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done it! With big help you guys :). The performance for to 150k of users is about 15-20 min which is nice in my opinion.

The code is:

```
#Import-Module ServerManager
#Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell


#Europe
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Server europe.mycompanyname.com -Filter * -Properties MemberOf #-ResultSetSize 1000

Write-Host Found ($users.count) users from europe

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname
    $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }
    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.samaccountname; "ADGroups" = $groups;}
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users from europe

$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -Path E:\temp\europe.csv


#NMEA

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Server nmea.mycompanyname.com -Filter * -Properties MemberOf #-ResultSetSize 1000

Write-Host Found ($users.count) users from nmea

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname
    $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }
    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.samaccountname; "ADGroups" = $groups;}
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users from nmea

$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -Path E:\temp\nmea.csv

#ASIAPACIFIC

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Server asiapacific.mycompanyname.com -Filter * -Properties MemberOf #-ResultSetSize 1000

Write-Host Found ($users.count) users from asiapacific

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname
    $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }
    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.samaccountname; "ADGroups" = $groups;}
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users from asiapacific

$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -Path E:\temp\asiapacific.csv

#americas

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Server americas.mycompanyname.com -Filter * -Properties MemberOf #-ResultSetSize 1000

Write-Host Found ($users.count) users from americas

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname
    $groups = if ($user.MemberOf) { $user.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' -join ';' | Out-String } else { '' }
    $entry = [Ordered]@{ "sAMAccountName" = $user.samaccountname; "ADGroups" = $groups;}
    $list.Add((New-Object psobject -Property $entry)) | Out-Null
}

Write-Host Processed ($list.count) users from americas
$list | Export-Csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -Path E:\temp\americas.csv
```

Comment: Glad I could help! I made a final edit to my answer, taking into account your code, just refactored to have a more flexible config and no duplicate code. Hope it helps!